# PC automatically power off while watching videos on chrome

Tags: crash

[psensor temp recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o07ge.png)my pc automatically power off while watching videos on chrome. there is an AMD RADEON HD 5450 2gb graphics card installed.
[this is my pc configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnUmq.png)

this is my pc configuration.

Comment: I'd have a look at the cpu temperature (there are apps that do this; `glances` shows temp of cpu core(s) and my radeon gpu but its resource-hungry; `psensor` etc are better suited for it) as if it reaches close to threshold (100oC on some) the system will turn off and there is nothing you can do about it.  Some cpus slow (really they pause) as they approach threshold-heat, but they'll still turn off with no warning (at head-threshold)

Comment: upgrading RAM solves this?

Comment: nope.  upgraded cooling is the only thing that will help IF its getting too hot, hence the recommendation to explore this via tools (`psensor` which does exactly this, or `glances` which is super easy to use even if resource-heavy).  **note:** excessive heat is a guess based on your description; you'll have to confirm the guess is correct or wrong, but note @Ashwin Geet D'Sa had the same reaction  (I hadn't see Ashwin's until I'd posted my comment)

Comment: thank you @guiverc. I can confirm by touching the body of CPU that it is the reason. can an air conditioner do any best?btw, psensor records following

Comment: temp 1       74 74 78

Comment: I`ve added the screenshot of psensor in the body

Comment: that's very warm - but I suspect not near your cpu's kill-temp (I don't know what it is for your cpu).  Watch it semi-regularly and see if you can note its 'temp' before it next dies on you. If your machine is turning off because of heat, it'll likely be 90oC+

Comment: okay, I`ll try it, bro.

Answer (score 1):

See to it that your system is not overheated. Usually overheated system automatically turn off.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your PC setup of a single core 2,8Ghz processor with 2GB RAM is below the [minimum requirements for Ubuntu Desktop Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) !

I'd suggest using **Lubuntu** since that is based on Ubuntu LTS but much more lightweight and has [very low minimum requirements](https://docs.lubuntu.net/).

Comment: is there any differences between them? according to performance.

Comment: yes, Lubuntu is using LXDE instead of gnome3, which performs much better on lower system specs, like yours.

Comment: Yes there are differences between them.  Underneath the Ubuntu **core** may be the same, but above that they are different, with different libs etc.  LXDE is less resource heavy, needs less memory meaning you'll need swap less etc. all of which can add to heat ...  The version of Ubuntu (and its DEsktop) makes a difference; if using Unity you can put it in a low-graphics-mode which will help if using a compatible version..  XFCE too is much lighter than Unity (or GNOME)

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the amount of resources that Google Chrome requires especially while playing videos, I bet the system was just overloaded. There is no way that amount of RAM and a single core CPU can handle the tasks you have been throwing at it even with the graphics card installed.

Comment: then there is no way to stop this rather than upgrading my pc. that's it?